# Background shape and position/offset it behind an image - CSS

Tags: html, css

What would be the best way to add a background color behind an image, shape it and offset it like the purple thing behind the image in the screenshot below?

[image]

The way I have done it in the snippet doesn't stay consistent across different device sizes, the shape and position varies every time the device size changes. I need to find a way where the shape position and shape stays proportionally same according to the size of the device.

```css
:root {
    --primary-blue: hsl(231, 69%, 60%);
    --primary-red: hsl(0, 94%, 66%);
    --neutral-blue-100: hsl(229, 8%, 60%);
    --neutral-blue-900: hsl(229, 31%, 21%);
    --neutral-100: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    --neutral-900: hsl(0, 0%, 0%); 
}

*, 
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0%;
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: 500;
}

img {
    display:block;
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
} 

.bg {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: translate(11%, 25%);
    width: 85%;
    height: 81%;
    background-color: var(--primary-blue);
    border-radius: 31% 0% 0% 28%;
}

.mt-3 {
    margin-top: 3em;
}

.content {
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Frontend Mentor | Bookmark landing page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <section class="hero mt-3">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="img-bg">
                    <span class="bg"></span>
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/r9cTpLM.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h1>A Simple Bookmark Manager</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use an `::after` element with `position: relative`, then you can use `top` and `left` etc to adjust the position.

Using an `::after` also fixes the centring, so you don't have to worry about that!

```css
.img-bg {
    position: relative;
}
    
.img-bg::before {
    content: "";
    width: 80%;
    z-index: -1;
  
    position: absolute;
        top: 30px;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
  
    background-color: var(--primary-blue);
    border-radius: 31% 0% 0% 28%;
}
```

---

Demo:

```css
:root {
    --primary-blue: hsl(231, 69%, 60%);
    --primary-red: hsl(0, 94%, 66%);
    --neutral-blue-100: hsl(229, 8%, 60%);
    --neutral-blue-900: hsl(229, 31%, 21%);
    --neutral-100: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    --neutral-900: hsl(0, 0%, 0%); 
}

*, 
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif; font-size: 18px; margin: 0%; text-align: center; }
h1 {font-weight: 500; }

img {
    display:block;
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
} 

.img-bg {
    position: relative;
}
    
.img-bg::before {
    content: "";
    width: 80%;
    z-index: -1;
  
    position: absolute;
        top: 30px;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
  
    background-color: var(--primary-blue);
    border-radius: 31% 0% 0% 28%;
}

.mt-3 {margin-top: 3em; }
.content {width: 85%; margin: 0 auto; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Frontend Mentor | Bookmark landing page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <section class="hero mt-3">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="img-bg">
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/r9cTpLM.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h1>A Simple Bookmark Manager</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: That partially works, but the issue is once I increase the device size the shape becomes small and goes behind the image, like this [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/YPGQ53p.png). I tried controlling the width and height using `vw` and `vh` units and percentage for the `top` property like: `width: 80vw`, `height: 24vh`, `top: 24%;` for the `.img_bg selector`, thinking it would be more consistent but the same issue still exists.